# How to resolve memory leak in Facebook Login Button?

Tags: android, facebook, leakcanary

I am using facebook SDK v4.25.0 in my app for Login purpose. When I am hitting Login button and open facebook login webview and now I am back pressing and back to login and again back pressing close the app. I am getting memory leak due to login button. Please help me to figured this out. Thanks in advance.

I am using following code to use Facebook Login functionality:

```
rlFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                loginButton = new LoginButton(mActivity);

                loginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList("public_profile, email"));
                loginButton.performClick();
                loginButton.setPressed(true);
                loginButton.invalidate();
                loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallBack);
                loginButton.setPressed(false);
                loginButton.invalidate();
            }
        });
```

Here is my unregister code onStop method:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(callbackManager != null)
        loginButton.unregisterCallback(callbackManager);

    if(loginButton != null)
        loginButton.invalidate();
}
```

Following is my LeakCanary trace result:

```
In com.xyz:1.0:1.
* com.xyz.ui.Login has leaked:
* GC ROOT static android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.mInstance
* references android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.mReceivers
* references java.util.HashMap.table
* references array java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[].[5]
* references java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry.key
* references com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver.this$0
* references com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.this$0 (anonymous subclass of com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker)
* references com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.mContext
* leaks com.xyz.ui.Login instance

* Retaining: 139 KB.
* Reference Key: 2026fe1b-3d96-4e51-acd2-bc08a4ebee45
* Device: motorola motorola Moto G Play harpia
* Android Version: 6.0.1 API: 23 LeakCanary: 1.5.1 1be44b3
* Durations: watch=636036ms, gc=141ms, heap dump=4181ms, analysis=301644ms

* Details:
* Class android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
|   static DEBUG = false
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[40]@316392961 (0x12dbc601)
|   static MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS = 1
|   static mLock = java.lang.Object@318106832 (0x12f5ecd0)
|   static mInstance = android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager@317589184 (0x12ee06c0)
|   static TAG = java.lang.String@314945344 (0x12c5af40)
* Instance of android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
|   static DEBUG = false
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[40]@316392961 (0x12dbc601)
|   static MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS = 1
|   static mLock = java.lang.Object@318106832 (0x12f5ecd0)
|   static mInstance = android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager@317589184 (0x12ee06c0)
|   static TAG = java.lang.String@314945344 (0x12c5af40)
|   mActions = java.util.HashMap@317539712 (0x12ed4580)
|   mAppContext = com.xyz.Application@317041376 (0x12e5aae0)
|   mHandler = android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1@317589216 (0x12ee06e0)
|   mPendingBroadcasts = java.util.ArrayList@317589248 (0x12ee0700)
|   mReceivers = java.util.HashMap@317539760 (0x12ed45b0)
|   shadow$_klass_ = android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
|   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
* Instance of java.util.HashMap
|   static MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 4
|   static serialPersistentFields = java.io.ObjectStreamField[1]@1881581904 (0x7026a950)
|   static EMPTY_TABLE = java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[2]@1881560712 (0x70265688)
|   static serialVersionUID = 362498820763181265
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[48]@1882175441 (0x702fb7d1)
|   static MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1073741824
|   static DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75
|   entryForNullKey = null
|   entrySet = null
|   keySet = null
|   modCount = 10
|   size = 4
|   table = java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[8]@317539808 (0x12ed45e0)
|   threshold = 6
|   values = null
|   keySet = null
|   valuesCollection = null
|   shadow$_klass_ = java.util.HashMap
|   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
* Array of java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry[]
|   [0] = null
|   [1] = java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry@317589280 (0x12ee0720)
|   [2] = java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry@317589312 (0x12ee0740)
|   [3] = null
|   [4] = null
|   [5] = java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry@317589344 (0x12ee0760)
|   [6] = null
|   [7] = null
* Instance of java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry
|   hash = 501765157
|   key = com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver@317589376 (0x12ee0780)
|   next = java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry@317589408 (0x12ee07a0)
|   value = java.util.ArrayList@317589440 (0x12ee07c0)
|   shadow$_klass_ = java.util.HashMap$HashMapEntry
|   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
* Instance of com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver
|   this$0 = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2@317589600 (0x12ee0860)
|   mDebugUnregister = false
|   mPendingResult = null
|   shadow$_klass_ = com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver
|   shadow$_monitor_ = -2087220166
* Instance of com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2
|   this$0 = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton@316577792 (0x12de9800)
|   broadcastManager = android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager@317589184 (0x12ee06c0)
|   isTracking = true
|   receiver = com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver@317589376 (0x12ee0780)
|   shadow$_klass_ = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2
|   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
* Instance of com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[8]@315707393 (0x12d15001)
|   static TAG = java.lang.String@318119072 (0x12f61ca0)
|   accessTokenTracker = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2@317589600 (0x12ee0860)
|   confirmLogout = true
|   loginLogoutEventName = java.lang.String@315137856 (0x12c89f40)
|   loginManager = com.facebook.login.LoginManager@317591888 (0x12ee1150)
|   loginText = null
|   logoutText = null
|   properties = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginButtonProperties@317589632 (0x12ee0880)
|   toolTipChecked = false
|   toolTipDisplayTime = 6000
|   toolTipMode = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$ToolTipMode@317589664 (0x12ee08a0)
|   toolTipPopup = null
|   toolTipStyle = com.facebook.login.widget.ToolTipPopup$Style@317591904 (0x12ee1160)
|   analyticsButtonCreatedEventName = java.lang.String@315137792 (0x12c89f00)
|   analyticsButtonTappedEventName = java.lang.String@315198336 (0x12c98b80)
|   externalOnClickListener = null
|   internalOnClickListener = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$LoginClickListener@317591920 (0x12ee1170)
|   overrideCompoundPadding = false
|   overrideCompoundPaddingLeft = 0
|   overrideCompoundPaddingRight = 0
|   parentFragment = null
|   mAllowTransformationLengthChange = false
|   mAutoLinkMask = 0
|   mBoring = null
|   mBreakStrategy = 0
|   mBufferType = android.widget.TextView$BufferType@1881595136 (0x7026dd00)
|   mChangeWatcher = null
|   mCharWrapper = null
|   mCurHintTextColor = 1627389952
|   mCurTextColor = -2
|   mCurrentSpellCheckerLocaleCache = null
|   mCursorDrawableRes = 17303275
|   mDeferScroll = -1
|   mDesiredHeightAtMeasure = -1
|   mDispatchTemporaryDetach = false
|   mDrawables = android.widget.TextView$Drawables@317053824 (0x12e5db80)
|   mEditableFactory = android.text.Editable$Factory@1881838280 (0x702a92c8)
|   mEditor = null
|   mEllipsize = null
|   mFilters = android.text.InputFilter[0]@1947019624 (0x740d2968)
|   mFirstTouch = false
|   mFreezesText = false
|   mGravity = 17
|   mHighlightColor = 1714105645
|   mHighlightPaint = android.graphics.Paint@317075072 (0x12e62e80)
|   mHighlightPath = null
|   mHighlightPathBogus = true
|   mHint = null
|   mHintBoring = null
|   mHintLayout = null
|   mHintTextColor = android.content.res.ColorStateList@317539952 (0x12ed4670)
|   mHorizontallyScrolling = false
|   mHyphenationFrequency = 0
|   mIncludePad = true
|   mLastLayoutDirection = -1
|   mLastScroll = 0
|   mLastTouchUpTime = 0
|   mLayout = null
|   mLinkTextColor = android.content.res.ColorStateList@317540000 (0x12ed46a0)
|   mLinksClickable = true
|   mListeners = null
|   mLocaleChanged = false
|   mMarquee = null
|   mMarqueeFadeMode = 0
|   mMarqueeRepeatLimit = 3
|   mMaxMode = 1
|   mMaxWidth = 2147483647
|   mMaxWidthMode = 2
|   mMaximum = 2147483647
|   mMinMode = 1
|   mMinWidth = 0
|   mMinWidthMode = 2
|   mMinimum = 0
|   mMovement = null
|   mOldMaxMode = 1
|   mOldMaximum = 2147483647
|   mPreDrawListenerDetached = false
|   mPreDrawRegistered = false
|   mPreventDefaultMovement = false
|   mRestartMarquee = false
|   mSavedHintLayout = null
|   mSavedLayout = null
|   mSavedMarqueeModeLayout = null
|   mScroller = null
|   mShadowColor = 0
|   mShadowDx = 0.0
|   mShadowDy = 0.0
|   mShadowRadius = 0.0
|   mSingleLine = false
|   mSpacingAdd = 0.0
|   mSpacingMult = 1.0
|   mSpannableFactory = android.text.Spannable$Factory@1881845520 (0x702aaf10)
|   mTempRect = null
|   mTemporaryDetach = false
|   mText = java.lang.String@316967808 (0x12e48b80)
|   mTextColor = android.content.res.ColorStateList@317540048 (0x12ed46d0)
|   mTextDir = null
|   mTextEditSuggestionItemLayout = 17367278
|   mTextPaint = android.text.TextPaint@317608112 (0x12ee50b0)
|   mTextSelectHandleLeftRes = 17303280
|   mTextSelectHandleRes = 17303283
|   mTextSelectHandleRightRes = 17303286
|   mTransformation = null
|   mTransformed = java.lang.String@316967808 (0x12e48b80)
|   mUserSetTextScaleX = false
|   mAccessibilityCursorPosition = -1
|   mAccessibilityDelegate = null
|   mAccessibilityTraversalAfterId = -1
|   mAccessibilityTraversalBeforeId = -1
|   mAccessibilityViewId = -1
|   mAnimator = null
|   mAttachInfo = null
|   mAttributes = null
|   mBackground = android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable@317075168 (0x12e62ee0)
|   mBackgroundRenderNode = null
|   mBackgroundResource = 2130837629
|   mBackgroundSizeChanged = true
|   mBackgroundTint = null
|   mBottom = 0
|   mCachingFailed = false
|   mClipBounds = null
|   mContentDescription = null
|   mContext = com.xyz.ui.Login@317612544 (0x12ee6200)
|   mCurrentAnimation = null
|   mDrawableState = int[2]@317589696 (0x12ee08c0)
|   mDrawingCache = null
|   mDrawingCacheBackgroundColor = 0
|   mFloatingTreeObserver = null
|   mForegroundInfo = null
|   mGhostView = null
|   mHasPerformedLongPress = false
|   mID = -1
|   mIgnoreNextUpEvent = false
|   mInContextButtonPress = false
|   mInputEventConsistencyVerifier = null
|   mKeyedTags = null
|   mLabelForId = -1
|   mLastIsOpaque = false
|   mLayerPaint = null
|   mLayerType = 0
|   mLayoutInsets = null
|   mLayoutParams = null
|   mLeft = 0
|   mLeftPaddingDefined = true
|   mListenerInfo = android.view.View$ListenerInfo@317034016 (0x12e58e20)
|   mMatchIdPredicate = null
|   mMatchLabelForPredicate = null
|   mMeasureCache = null
|   mMeasuredHeight = 0
|   mMeasuredWidth = 0
|   mMinHeight = 0
|   mMinWidth = 0
|   mNestedScrollingParent = null
|   mNextFocusDownId = -1
|   mNextFocusForwardId = -1
|   mNextFocusLeftId = -1
|   mNextFocusRightId = -1
|   mNextFocusUpId = -1
|   mOldHeightMeasureSpec = -2147483648
|   mOldWidthMeasureSpec = -2147483648
|   mOutlineProvider = android.view.ViewOutlineProvider$1@1881594864 (0x7026dbf0)
|   mOverScrollMode = 1
|   mOverlay = null
|   mPaddingBottom = 10
|   mPaddingLeft = 12
|   mPaddingRight = 12
|   mPaddingTop = 10
|   mParent = null
|   mPendingCheckForLongPress = null
|   mPendingCheckForTap = null
|   mPerformClick = null
|   mPrivateFlags = -2128605184
|   mPrivateFlags2 = 1188872
|   mPrivateFlags3 = 0
|   mRecreateDisplayList = false
|   mRenderNode = android.view.RenderNode@317589728 (0x12ee08e0)
|   mResources = android.content.res.Resources@316988480 (0x12e4dc40)
|   mRight = 0
|   mRightPaddingDefined = true
|   mScrollCache = null
|   mScrollIndicatorDrawable = null
|   mScrollX = 0
|   mScrollY = 0
|   mSendViewScrolledAccessibilityEvent = null
|   mSendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent = null
|   mSendingHoverAccessibilityEvents = false
|   mStartActivityRequestWho = null
|   mStateListAnimator = null
|   mSystemUiVisibility = 0
|   mTag = null
|   mTempNestedScrollConsumed = null
|   mTop = 0
|   mTouchDelegate = null
|   mTouchSlop = 16
|   mTransformationInfo = null
|   mTransientStateCount = 0
|   mTransitionName = null
|   mUnscaledDrawingCache = null
|   mUnsetPressedState = null
|   mUserPaddingBottom = 10
|   mUserPaddingEnd = -2147483648
|   mUserPaddingLeft = 12
|   mUserPaddingLeftInitial = 12
|   mUserPaddingRight = 12
|   mUserPaddingRightInitial = 12
|   mUserPaddingStart = -2147483648
|   mVerticalScrollFactor = 0.0
|   mVerticalScrollbarPosition = 0
|   mViewFlags = 402669569
|   mWindowAttachCount = 0
|   shadow$_klass_ = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
|   shadow$_monitor_ = 0
* Instance of com.xyz.ui.Login
|   static $staticOverhead = byte[16]@316633089 (0x12df7001)
|   static serialVersionUID = 8377811411653900550
|   static $change = null
|   callbackManager = com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl@317591952 (0x12ee1190)
|   etEmail = android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText@316578816 (0x12de9c00)
|   etPassword = android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText@316579840 (0x12dea000)
|   isButtonChecked = false
|   loginButton = com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton@316577792 (0x12de9800)
|   mActivity = com.xyz.ui.Login@317612544 (0x12ee6200)
|   mCallBack = com.xyz.ui.Login$6@317591968 (0x12ee11a0)
|   socialType = 0
|   bmpUser = null
|   dialogShown = false
|   imgCaptureImage = null
|   imgExtra = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView@316724736 (0x12e0d600)
|   imgMenu = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView@316725248 (0x12e0d800)
|   imgRefresh = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView@316725760 (0x12e0da00)
|   imgUser = null
|   mActionBarAutoHideEnabled = false
|   mActionBarToolbar = android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar@316580864 (0x12dea400)
|   mActivity = com.xyz.ui.Login@317612544 (0x12ee6200)
|   mDeferredOnDrawerClosedRunnable = null
|   mDrawerLayout = null
|   mHandler = android.os.Handler@317589760 (0x12ee0900)
|   mNavDrawerItemViews = null
|   mNavDrawerItems = java.util.ArrayList@317589792 (0x12ee0920)
|   mNormalStatusBarColor = -16777216
|   mThemedStatusBarColor = -16777216
|   objInputMethodManager = null
|   resEntity = null
|   rlExtra = android.widget.RelativeLayout@316581888 (0x12dea800)
|   selectedImagePath = java.lang.String@1878218728 (0x6ff357e8)
|   txtNotificationBg = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@316582912 (0x12deac00)
|   txtSave = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@316583936 (0x12deb000)
|   txtTitle = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView@316584960 (0x12deb400)
|   viewExtra = android.view.View@315213344 (0x12c9c620)
|   mDelegate = android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23@317203696 (0x12e824f0)
|   mEatKeyUpEvent = false
|   mResources = null
|   mThemeId = 2131427473
|   mCreated = true
|   mFragments = android.support.v4.app.FragmentController@317591984 (0x12ee11b0)
|   mHandler = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1@317589824 (0x12ee0940)
|   mNextCandidateRequestIndex = 0
|   mOptionsMenuInvalidated = false
|   mPendingFragmentActivityResults = android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat@317589856 (0x12ee0960)
|   mReallyStopped = true
|   mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = false
|   mResumed = false
|   mRetaining = false
|   mStopped = true
|   mStartedActivityFromFragment = false
|   mStartedIntentSenderFromFragment = false
|   mExtraDataMap = android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap@317589888 (0x12ee0980)
|   mActionBar = null
|   mActionModeTypeStarting = 0
|   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo@317053952 (0x12e5dc00)
|   mActivityTransitionState = android.app.ActivityTransitionState@317120256 (0x12e6df00)
|   mApplication = com.xyz.Application@317041376 (0x12e5aae0)
|   mCalled = true
|   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
|   mChangingConfigurations = false
|   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName@317592000 (0x12ee11c0)
|   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
|   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration@317608224 (0x12ee5120)
|   mDecor = null
|   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
|   mDefaultKeySsb = null
|   mDestroyed = true
|   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
|   mEmbeddedID = null
|   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
|   mEnterTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1@1881597248 (0x7026e540)
|   mExitTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1@1881597248 (0x7026e540)
|   mFinished = true
|   mFragments = android.app.FragmentController@317592016 (0x12ee11d0)
|   mHandler = android.os.Handler@317589920 (0x12ee09a0)
|   mHasCurrentPermissionsRequest = false
|   mIdent = 67478760
|   mInstanceTracker = android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker@317592032 (0x12ee11e0)
|   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation@317034096 (0x12e58e70)
|   mIntent = android.content.Intent@317120320 (0x12e6df40)
|   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
|   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread@314585344 (0x12c03100)
|   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList@317589952 (0x12ee09c0)
|   mManagedDialogs = null
|   mMenuInflater = null
|   mParent = null
|   mReferrer = java.lang.String@317120384 (0x12e6df80)
|   mResultCode = 0
|   mResultData = null
|   mResumed = false
|   mSearchEvent = null
|   mSearchManager = null
|   mStartedActivity = false
|   mStopped = true
|   mTemporaryPause = false
|   mTitle = java.lang.String@317018560 (0x12e551c0)
|   mTitleColor = 0
|   mTitleReady = true
|   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy@317589984 (0x12ee09e0)
|   mTranslucentCallback = null
|   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread@1945952928 (0x73fce2a0)
|   mVisibleBehind = false
|   mVisibleFromClient = true
|   mVisibleFromServer = true
|   mVoiceInteractor = null
|   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@314869152 (0x12c485a0)
|   mWindowAdded = true
|   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl@317590016 (0x12ee0a00)
|   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater@317540096 (0x12ed4700)
|   mOverrideConfiguration = null
|   mResources = android.content.res.Resources@316988480 (0x12e4dc40)
|   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme@317590048 (0x12ee0a20)
|   mThemeResource = 2131427473
|   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@317054080 (0x12e5dc80)
|   shadow$_klass_ = com.xyz.ui.Login
|   shadow$_monitor_ = -2015956359
* Excluded Refs:
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedView
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedInputConnection
| Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView
| Field: android.os.UserManager.mContext
| Field: android.net.ConnectivityManager.sInstance
| Field: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue (always)
| Thread:FinalizerWatchdogDaemon (always)
| Thread:main (always)
| Thread:LeakCanary-Heap-Dump (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.WeakReference (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.SoftReference (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.PhantomReference (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.Finalizer (always)
| Class:java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference (always)
```

Comment: shouldn't you unregister mCallback?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Please check my edited question.

Comment: @Philliphe Any solution on that? Having the same issue here

Comment: @JonathanSantos did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I decided to make a clone since I could not fix the leak

```
XML
<Button android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
          android:drawableStart="@drawable/com_facebook_button_icon_white"
          android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue"
          android:text=" Continue with Facebook"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

Then use `LoginManager` to handle the callbacks.
Log user in with:

```
LoginManager.getInstance()
            .logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
```

in the `OnClickListener`.
Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after ages trying to find a solution I could manage it simply by setting the Facebook LoginButton reference to null. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mPresenter.release();
    mPresenter = null;
    mHost = null;

    if(buttonFacebook != null && facebookCallbackManager != null){
        buttonFacebook.unregisterCallback(facebookCallbackManager);
        buttonFacebook = null;
        facebookCallbackManager = null;
    }
}
```

PS: I'm using FacebookButton inside a fragment, that's why I'm releasing it on *onDetach* method. In a case where it's being used in an Activity, just release it either in *onDestroy* or *onStop* (remember *onDestroy* might not be called in some situations and *onStop* might be called when the Activity is not being actually destroyed).